# Python how can I read huge binary file(>25GB)?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, binaryfiles, readfile, bigdata

I have N-body simulation data and have to read that file in python.

Its size is over 25GB so file.read() is not work by lack of memory.

So I wrote the code like this

```
with open("fullFoF_merger.cbin.z0.Run1", "rb") as mergertree:
    def param(data):
        result = {"nowhid":data[0], "nexthid":data[2],"zi":data[10], 
                  "zip1":data[11], "F":data[4], "mass":data[9], 
                  "dlnM":data[5],"dM":data[12], "dlnJ":data[6],"dJ":data[13],
                  "dlnspin": data[7], "spin":data[8],
                  "G":data[14], "overden":data[15]}
        return result

    num = 0

    while 1:
        num +=1

        binary_data = mergertree.read(4)

        if not binary_data : break

        n_max = struct.unpack('I', binary_data)


        binary_data = mergertree.read(64*n_max[0])

        Halo = [None]*n_max[0]


        for i in range(1,n_max[0]+1):
            data = struct.unpack("4i12f", binary_data[64*(i-1):64*(i)])
            Halo[i-1] = param(data)

        MergerQ = []+Halo


print(MergerQ)

print(num)

print("\n Run time \n --- %d seconds ---" %(time.time()-start_time))
```

In this process while loop calculate 45470522 times in this code. But when I print MergerQ in python it shows only one dictionary data like this

```
[{'nowhid': 53724, 'nexthid': 21912952, 'zi': 0.019874930381774902, 'zip1': -1.6510486602783203e-05, 'F': inf, 'mass': 67336740864.0, 'dlnM': 0.0, 'dM': 0.0, 'dlnJ': 0.1983184665441513, 'dJ': 8463334768640.0, 'dlnspin': 0.19668935239315033, 'spin': 0.012752866372466087, 'G': inf, 'overden': 1.0068886280059814}]
```

I think it caused by lack of memory or memory limit of python's variables.

How can I solve this problem?

Is there any way to read whole data and save in python variables?

Parallel computing can be the solution of this code?

I will waiting for your comment. Thank you.

Comment: I you wish to load everything into a dict, you are never going to make it without buying more RAM. What are you then doing with that data ?

Comment: On every loop iteration you reset MergerQ.  But it looks like your code won't really help because you still seem to be loading all of the data, you're just doing it a bit at a time.  You won't be able to make use of the data unless you can actually do the processing incrementally.  For instance, if you had to sum a value from each record, you could read one record at a time, update your sum, and then throw away the actual record.  But you can't keep all of the data from all the records; it will take too much memory.

Comment: I will read all of data and then sort the data by zi, mass and overden.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
MergerQ = []+Halo
```

You clear `MergerQ`, put it outside of your loop instead:

```
num = 0
MergerQ = []

while 1:
    ...
    MergerQ += Halo
```

**But don't expect to have the amount of memory you need to store the entire thing if your file is that big, you'll need a lot of memory and a lot of time.**

*Edit*

Its very possible that you'll be able to successfully run your code without as much physical RAM would be needed as your OS will likely store it in your hard disk fetching it when needed, but this will **massively** increase run time.

Try running this code snippet and seeing what happens (*forewarning: if you leave this running too long your machine will become unresponsive and most likely need physically reset*)

```
a = []
while 1:
    a = [a, a]
```

Expect your script to react similarly.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think about parallel processing to decrease run time. If I use my own laptop parallel processing will decrease a lot of time?

Comment: Honestly I haven't done a lot of PP but to the best of my knowledge it will decrease run time but increase memory usage